# Permission denied for mkdir

Tags: python, python-os

I installed **my own package**  via `sudo python setup.py install` locally. In its source code there's the code which causes `OSError: (13, 'Permission denied', '....')`:

```
curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(curr_dir, "dir1/log1.out"))):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(os.path.join(curr_dir, "dir1/log1.out")))
```

curr_dir is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_app-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/my_app
```

And:

```
$ ls -al '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_app-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/my_app'
total 696
drwxr-xr-x  35 root  admin   1190 Mar 29 12:00 .
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  admin    136 Mar 29 12:00 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    108 Mar 29 12:00 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    202 Mar 29 12:00 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  11964 Mar 29 12:00 file1.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  12953 Mar 29 12:00 file1.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  13424 Mar 29 12:00 file2.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  15621 Mar 29 12:00 file2.pyc
.....
```

How can I fix it?

P.S. Even I create a file `curr_dir, "dir1/log1.out` manually by mkdir and touch, the python code also throws the same exception while being executed.

Comment: Do not install packages using `sudo pip` - that is highly discouraged because of various problems associated with this approach. Instead, follow the Python community best practices and create virtual environments for installing your packages: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, I'm not installing it using sudo pip.

Comment: You should use sudo to access that directory. You can try changing the permission with chmod 755 to allow permission to your user. But what distro and what package are you installing?

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi, my own.

Comment: @MarioHonse: No sudo, in whatever context when installing Python packages. Please create virtual environments and sudo is not needed for installing anything.

Comment: You should know that whatever is in /usr is owned by root

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi, in order to run "python setup.py install" one has to use sudo.

Comment: If you say that you couldn't create directory manually, then it seems the problem relates to your OS. `OSError: (13, 'Permission denied', '....')` what output is there in '....'?

Comment: @srekcahrai, I didn't say that.

Comment: @MarioHonse "...manually by mkdir and touch..." at last

Comment: @srekcahrai, I didn't say I couldn't create it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I installed my own package via `sudo python setup.py install` locally.

Once you used `sudo` (which you should not do), all files that your package includes are owned by root because its the root user that is running `setup.py install`.

Now, when you try to run any module that is included in the package as your normal user, and that module tries to open/modify/read/create any directory or file that is part of the package itself, it will run into permission problems.  All files for your package are owned by root, and you are trying to run it with your normal user, and that user cannot create directories in the package's source path (which is referred to here `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`.

The solution to your problem is to first, uninstall the module (you can simply delete the entire tree as root).

Next, as your *normal user*, create a virtual environment and install your package. This will make sure that:

1. Your package isn't installed in the global Python package repository.
2. Files for your package are owned by your normal user account.
3. Any file-level operations can be performed properly without using elevated permissions (like sudo).

Now, if you need to create these directories as part of your package's setup procedure, then you need to modify your `setup.py`.